# when dplyr/accross function use for data.table, the speed is slow

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, across

Using dplyr/accross is very easy to summarize numeric variables which group by character variables (no need input variable names).
Across can use to data.table but  the speed will slow (just as manipulate  dataframe ) .

Is the any way for not lost speed and convenience ? Thanks!

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
test_data <- data.table(x=c('a','b','c','a','b','c'),y=c('d','e','f','d','e','f'),a=c(1:6),b=c(1,7,NA,3,5,6),c=c(NA,3,NA,4,7,8))
test_data %>% group_by(across(where(is.character))) %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.number),function(x) sum(x,na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Comment: (1) You're using `dplyr` verbs on a `data.table`. Unless you're also loading the `dtplyr`, it will not do things in a canonical/fast `data.table`-manner, so it will be "normal dplyr fast" (not data.table-fast). (2) `is.number` is not found, are you loading any other packages? (3) What makes you think this is slow? A `data.table`-canonical method could be `test_data[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = c(names(test_data)[sapply(test_data, is.character)])]`.

Comment: thank for your replay , I will try to load paclage dtplyr meanwhile

Comment: `is.number` supposed to be `is.numeric`? If not, what package is it from?

Comment: it's  is.numeric , sorry for wrong input

Answer (score 4):

Working directly with `data.table`:

```
char_columns <- sapply(test_data, is.character) |> which() |> names()

test_data[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = is.numeric, by = char_columns]

#    x y a  b  c
# 1: a d 5  4  4
# 2: b e 7 12 10
# 3: c f 9  6  8
```